# How to calculate the percentage of a year up to a date is of the whole?

Tags: google-sheets

Given a date, I need to calculate the percentage of its position in the year. So that 31-12-2015 would return `1`, or `100%`, because it's the 365th day of 365 days in that year. And 1-1-2015 would return 0,274% (1/365).

I have a long formula solution

```
=MINUS(
  A1;
  DATE(YEAR(A1)-1;12;31)
) / MINUS(
  DATE(YEAR(A1);1;1);
  DATE(YEAR(A1)+1;1;1)
)
```

Basically it counts the day of the year of the date given in A1 and divides that by the number of days in that year.

Is there a way to do this with a shorter formula?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a shorter formula that is equivalent to yours, using [`yearfrac`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3092989?hl=en):

```
=yearfrac(date(year(A1), 1, 1), A1, 1)
```

However, the formula you have is inconsistent with your description, since it returns 0 for 1-1-2015, representing that at the *beginning* of that day, no time has elapsed since the beginning of the year. To have 1/365 for 1-1-2015 and 1 for 12-31-2015, add 1 to the date, to calculate each day's *end*:

```
=yearfrac(date(year(A1), 1, 1), A1+1, 1)
```

Answer (score 2):

## Short answer

Besides the use of other functions, like YEARFRAC() as was [suggested](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/89453/88163) by [Live Forever](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/users/79865/live-forever), usually the way to get the shorter formula is to use a custom function.

## Example

A Custom function

```
/**
 * Calculates the progress of the year for the date provided.
 * 
 * @param {DATE(2015,1,1)} input - The date to calculate the progress of the year.
 * @customfunction
 */
function YEARPROGRESS(adate) {
  if(adate instanceof Date){   
    var start = new Date(adate.getFullYear(), 0, 0);
    var day = Math.floor(adate - start);
    var end = new Date(adate.getFullYear(), 11, 31)
    var days = Math.floor(end - start);
    return day/days;
  } else {
    throw new Error('adate should be a valid date' );
  }
}
```

#### Use examples

```
=YEARPROGRESS(A1)  
=YEARPROGRESS(DATE(2015,1,1))
```

Use the cell formatting options to display the result as percentage.

### Custom function names

If you want to save even more characters, you could name your function as short as a single alphabetic character (A..Z) but this is not a good practice as this could make a bit harder to remember how was named.

From the reference

> #### Naming
>
> In addition to the standard conventions for naming JavaScript
>   functions, be aware of the following:
>
> - The name of a custom function must be distinct from the names of
>     built-in functions like SUM().
> - The name of a custom function cannot end with an underscore (_), which denotes a private function in Apps Script.
> - The name of a custom function must be declared with the syntax
>     function myFunction(), not var myFunction = new Function().
> - Capitalization does not matter, although the names of spreadsheet
>     functions are traditionally uppercase.

## References

- [Custom functions - Guides - Google Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions)